# Upperbound of the minimum of the sum of two functions

Tags: functions

Suppose you have two functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ and you know the minimum and the maximum values of each function. What's a good upperbound for the minimum value of $f_1+f_2$?
I thought $\min(\min(f_1)+\max(f_2),\max(f_1)+\min(f_2))$, what do you think?

Comment: it seems the best possible, with so little information

Comment: Now, suppose that instead of having the exact maximum and minimum values of the functions, you have the upperbounds, would it still work?